# How to Import from Module in Parent Directory (Python)

Tags: import, package, python-import, relative-import

I have the file structure:

```
directory_1/
    file_1.py
    directory_2/
        directory_3/
            file_2.py
```

How can I import a function from `file_1` into `file_2`?

Other answers have led me to try `from ...file_1 import fun`, after adding an `__init__.py` file to `directory_1`, but doing this gives me `ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package`. I have also tried `from directory_1.file_1 import fun` but this has given me a `ModuleNotFound` error.

If anybody could help I would be very grateful!

Answer (score 0):

### Solution

```
import os
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "../..")))

from file_1 import fun
fun()
```

#### Umm?

This solution is messy but the only way to avoid it is by restructuring you project, having a look at [this](https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/structure/) might help.